# Bind mouse button to previous/next song?

Tags: mouse

I'm not using the two buttons on the side of my mouse, and would like to bind them to the previous/next song commands like the ones on my keyboard.

It's a Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 and I've downloaded the software for it, but don't see any default commands that look like what I want.

It allows binding to a macro, but I don't know what I'd have to put in the program either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [compile](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/) script for each action and then assign the resulting EXE files to the buttons using the mouse driver software.

For the **Next** media key, compile:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#NoTrayIcon
SendInput, {Media_Next}
ExitApp
```

For **Previous**:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#NoTrayIcon
SendInput, {Media_Prev}
ExitApp
```

Comment: didn't even think of that, good work!